# Porque razón obtengo poca precisión con mi modelo de red neuronal densa definida con tensorflow/keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, redes-neuronales

Me encuentro realizando un trabajo para mi universidad y en este momento necesito crear y entrenar un modelo de red neuronal densa con la librería keras.
Mi inconveniente es que al crear el modelo y entrenarlo con un dataset guardado en un csv con el siguiente formato:
[image: dataset en CSV]

no logro superar el 0.35(35%) de precisión sobre las predicciones de la red neuronal.
He probado de todo, añadiendo mas cantidad de neuronas, cambiando las funciones de activación, agregando dropout para generar ruido y así poder obtener diferentes resultados, varié entre épocas de entrenamiento y varié el batch_size pero no logre dar con la solución.
Nose si el error esta en el dataset o en el modelo, dejo la definicion del modelo a continuacion:[image: definicion y prueba de precision]

Comment: Edita la pregunta y coloca código para que cualquier usuario que quiera ayudarte, tenga el camino más fácil, así aumentas las chances de obtener respuestas. Aquí otras recomendaciones para formular preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> aquí te informas sobre el sitio y consigues tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Comment: podrías poner el proyecto en la nube para dar mas revisión
https://colab.research.google.com/  saludos